# Repeat actions in slow motion, for presentation purposes

Tags: keyboard-macros, automation, screencast

I would like to repeat actions (preferably as a keyboard macro, but I am open to other solutions), in some kind of automated, "slow motion".  By "slow motion", I mean at a speed that is close to human pace, rather than usual full speed of `C-x e`.

The goal is to be able to prepare actions then play them again during a presentation, or in order to capture them in a screencast (a bit like the GIF at the top of http://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/, or the videos in http://emacsgifs.github.io/).

There are of course a lot of information about automating tasks, and creating macros in Emacs, but nothing about slowing their repetition.

Comment: See elisp manual node on [Waiting for Elapsed Time or Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html).

Comment: Thank you.  But as far as I understand, this is for "pausing" for some time, and has to be called explicitly.  I was hoping for something a bit more automated, and to give the impression that a human is actually typing (when typing text).

Comment: Why not capture them first and then slow down the replay by editing the resulting recording (animated GIF or whatever)? I don't think Emacs offers much help for this, but it should be possible to edit the result outside of Emacs.

Comment: You shouldn't slow down your typing as much as the parts where you need to give explanations. Probably a tricky problem as is.

Comment: @Drew Well, I think this is about being able to write it once then repeat it as it changes.

Comment: @YoungFrog This is to create an animated GIF, so it is quite short, and we need to get time to see what's written down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I've just discovered the tag `screencast` (I added it to my question as well), which contained 2 questions:

- [how to repeat actions in slow motion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27162/), which contains a link to [package-demo](https://github.com/vermiculus/package-demo)
- [how to record an Emacs frame](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/798/) and transform it to a GIF, with a link to [camcorder.el](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/camcorder.el)

Even though `package-demo` is quite simple, it is enough for my simple needs, and combining them together allows to develop the screencast incrementally and repeat the recording.  Here is a simple example how to mix them both:

```
(package-demo--run-demo
 '((M-x eshell)
   (M-x camcorder-record)
   (pause 1)
   (typewriter "ls -aol")
   (pause 1)
   (kbd "RET")))
```

[This file](https://github.com/fgeorges/mlproj-web/blob/master/dev/gif-script.md) contains more notes and examples.  The result is [there](https://github.com/fgeorges/mlproj-web/blob/master/src/images/mlproj-intro.gif) or live on http://mlproj.org/ homepage.

Comment: There also [gif-screencast](https://gitlab.com/ambrevar/emacs-gif-screencast). And for editing the gif afterwards I recommend GIMP, which lets you adjust the delays between frames.